# Image out of imageview on app startup

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Image is set out of imageview on app startup as shown in screenshot and fixes automatically on imageview click.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to fit image on startup itself.

Sorry,if i wasnt able to ask question properly.if any doubts pls ask me.

item_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkboxItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Tea" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearRate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsImageView
            android:id="@+id/textSubtractRate"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:iiv_color="@color/md_grey_400"

             />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textRate"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="3" />

        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsImageView
            android:id="@+id/textAddRate"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:iiv_color="@color/md_green_600"
            app:iiv_icon="faw_plus_circle"
            app:iiv_size="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try using scaletypes. use fit inside or center inside.

Comment: What kind of filetype is Your faw_plus_circle - drawable, vector? Please fix Your xml so we could reuse it during tests. I believe there should be `app:iiv_icon="@drawable/faw_plus_circle`

Comment: its a vector image fetched directly using font awesome library.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkboxItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Tea" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearRate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textSubtractRate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textRate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textAddRate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Any explanation would be sufficient. Could You share some information?

Answer (score 0):

Because your `linearRate` layout's weight width (0.8) is not enough for the images and the text.
If your intention for using `layout_weight` is for giving the rest of the empty space for the Checkbox, remove the `android:weightSum="2"` from the root layout, remove the weight from `linearRate`, and make `checkboxItem`'s weight 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this and let us know your feedback..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkboxItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Tea" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearRate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textSubtractRate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_indeterminate_check_box" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textRate"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textAddRate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_box" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: it didnt work same issue at startup imageview is misaligned

Comment: First please create proper size image from this site https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html